# Access a modbus device with Raspberry Pi and a browser

Tags: php, modbus

First, my environment:
Raspberry Pi3B; Raspbian o/s; PhpEpsolarTracer package; php5; Apache; etc.
   I'm reading data from a modbus device and writing to a file. I do this in a SSH session. When I write a script that reads the modbus device and try to run the script froma web browser, the script always fails. Simple and ordinary php scripts work in the browser. I'm using a php package designed for the device I'm using, a solar charge controller. The package is from github :

github.com/toggio/PhpEpsolarTracer

As I mentioned, there are no problems running anything from SSH, only in a browser window. There is one proprietary script, example_web.php that writes an html page containing sample reads from the device. The page comes up with a "Disconnected" message speicfied in the script if no connection is made. No clue as to why the connection was not made. I think the Modbus RTU mode is used.

There are only four files required, including the calling script.
I've placed all the code in 'var/www/html' and made them all executable and in the root group. I run a SSH session from within that directory successfully, still no data on the web.

Any ideas on how to make the "Connected" state?

Comment: I've decided to make the php script into a daemon and access the csv file created and updated by the daemon.

Comment: The deamonization of the PHP script, using systemd, was a success. I can now access a text file in csv format from a browser. The file is continuously updated and a new file is created each day.